# Use logic laws to show $q \iff (¬p \lor ¬q) \equiv \neg p \land q$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

The question asks me to find a simpler statement that is logically equivalent with $ q \iff (\neg p \lor ¬q)$. I believe this should be $\neg p \land q$ and am required to prove it with logic laws. I'm really struggling with find the right logic laws that take me to the answer.

This is what I have currently:

Starting with LHS:
$ q \iff (\neg p \lor ¬q) \equiv \neg p \land q $

Then, using a known equivalence:

$ (q \land (\neg p \lor \neg q)) \lor (\neg q \land \neg(\neg p \lor \neg q))$

Then following De Morgan's Laws

$ (q \land (\neg p \lor ¬q)) \lor (\neg q \land (\neg\neg p \land \neg\neg q)) $

Then the double negation law

$ (q \land (\neg p \lor \neg q)) \lor (\neg q \land (p \land q)) $

Comment: This question is suspiciously similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409613/discrete-maths-logically-equivalent/2409629#2409629...

Comment: @5xum just much worse in terms of question-writing skills

Comment: @KennyLau Not really, if you saw the original version of the linked question...

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Very encouraging to a new user, thanks guys. I apologise for not using Math Jax. I'm guessing the other person and I are probably trying to finish the same assignment at the last minute. I will work through your solutions over there and come back here if I'm still stuck.

Comment: I've edited your question to use MathJAX. A tip is that you can edit your question (without saving) and see how it was done - that can work as a starting point for formatting future posts (then of course you have the tutorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can continue where you left off:

$ (q \land (\neg p \lor \neg q)) \lor (\neg q \land (p \land q)) $

Then you use complement law (ie $\neg q \land q \equiv \bot)$ together with associative and commutative law:

$(q \land (\neg p \lor \neg q)) \lor (\bot \land p) $

And anihilation and identity (ie $\bot\land p\equiv\bot)$ and $\phi\lor\bot\equiv\phi$):

$q \land (\neg p \lor \neg q)$

Distributive law:

$(q \land \neg p) \lor (q \land \neg q)$

And finally complement and identity:

$q \land \neg p$

Comment: Thanks so so so much, this makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **hint** in the form of an analytic tableau:

[image].

You start with the negation of $$(q\leftrightarrow(\lnot p\lor \lnot q))\leftrightarrow(\lnot p\land q)$$ then proceed to use a few contradiction-hunting rules to eliminate all possibilities.

Each path ends in a contradiction, so the tableau is closed and thus the result follows.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand how that works at all

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux) will help.